Outputting dataset with "fraction overlap" between two types of areas
I have two shapefiles: one containing boundaries for Census tracts, and one containing boundaries for "districts". In my case, districts are larger than Census tracts and, additionally, Census tracts do not fit "neatly" within districts.
I'd like to do the following in Python:

Find out how much of each Census tract falls within each district. In particular, it could be the case that one Census tract has overlap with multiple districts.
Output a simple pandas dataframe where each row contains: (1) the district ID, (2) the tract ID, and (3) what fraction of that Census tract falls within that district.

I've trying to get my bearings with GeoPandas and Shapely.
Can you provide any guidance on how to do this?

You have to add your code attempt (whatever you have) to your question or it is going to get closed. Can you add a screenshot showing the polygons?

Intersect, groupby:
import geopandas as gpd

district = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/district.gpkg")
#print(district.columns)
#Index(['district_name', 'geometry'], dtype='object')


census = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/census.shp")
census["census_area"] = census.area
#print(census.columns)
#Index(['id', 'tract_id', 'geometry', 'census_area'], dtype='object')

inter = gpd.overlay(district, census, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True, make_valid=True)
# print(inter.columns)
# Index(['district_name', 'id', 'tract_id', 
#        'census_area', 'geometry'], dtype='object')

#Calculate the area after intersection
inter["interarea"] = inter.area

#Group by district and tract id
grp = inter.groupby(["district_name", "tract_id"], as_index=True)

#Sum the intersectionarea per district and tract, divide by the original census area

result = grp.apply(lambda x: x.interarea.sum() / x.census_area.max(), 
                   include_groups=False).reset_index(name="Fraction")

# result.head(10)
#   district_name  tract_id  Fraction
# 0             A        37  0.157010 #16 % of tract 37's total area is in district A
# 1             A        38  0.011120
# 2             A        45  0.017157
# 3             A        46  0.005635
# 4             B        35  0.065655
# 5             B        36  0.017990
# 6             B        43  0.066792
# 7             B        44  0.043829
# 8             C        45  0.159571
# 9             C        46  0.225229



Thank you so much!! I see the census_area column being used in the lambda function in the gpr.apply but Ccn I ask why it was necessary to create the district_area column? Where does it get used?

Ah, thank you for clarifying! Some more clarifying questions:


If interarea is already the area of the intersection, why is the sum() x.interarea.sum() necessary?


Similarly, why is the max() necessary in x.census_area.max()?


And actually, why is the groupby necessary? Once we intersect, doesn't each row in the resulting dataframe already correspond to a tract-district intersection? How come we can't get the Fraction column by doing inter["interarea"]/inter["census_area"]?


Thank you in advance!

Am also confused about what the groupby is for if the apply sets include_groups=False. Also a bit confused about why reset_index is used to create the new column "Fraction" (I looked in the pandas docs and didn't any parameter named name, although the code works great).
Sorry about this! I'm very new to working with these tools but I really want to make sure I understand every line. Thank you so much.

Gotcha; thank you so much! Would it be possible to explain the other two questions as well (about the .sum() and .max())? Thank you!

Got it; thank you so much!
